# how to avoid delete files that comes from gdm-session & cause of increasing used /var

Tags: linux, rhel, process, lsof, gdm

from `lsof` we can see the following output

```
lsof /var | grep delete
rsyslogd   9664      root    4w   REG  253,2 25589554694  67267903 /var/log/messages-20210513 (deleted)
rsyslogd   9664      root    7w   REG  253,2  9865832185  67294059 /var/log/secure-20210619 (deleted)
libvirtd   9666      root   21r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)
qmgr      10241   postfix    8r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)
gdm-sessi 13304      root    8r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)   <-----------------------
dbus-daem 14198       gdm    4r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)
dbus-daem 14535       gdm    5r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)
sssd      16743      root   15r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)
sssd_be   16746      root   22r   REG  253,2    10406312 134328488 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)
```

after investigation we saw that `gdm-session` takes `~40G` from /`var` as deleted file

so after we killed the PID --> `13304`

we decreased `/var` from `98%` used to `59.4G` used

since we are dealing with **very important production server**

we want to know if we can avoid such of this behaviors that some deleted file as `gdm-session` can crash the OS by reaching `/var` to became `100%`

- /var size is 100G

appreciate for any useful suggestion ?

Comment: why does your "very important production server" run `gdm-session`?!  Why would you want a graphical login manager on a production server!??!?

Comment: "Why would you want a graphical login manager on a production server" , do you mean that we should stop the gdm service?

Comment: as --> systemctl stop gdm.service  & systemctl disable gdm.service  ??

Comment: yes. also, uninstall it? Alongside with all the stuff you don't need when you don't need a graphical desktop? You should think about what kind of things you want to run on your "very important production server", if it's very important.

Comment: Also note that these are `sss`'s files, and you might very well be looking at the wrong thing. We don't know your sssd setup, so we can't advise.

Comment: just to be sure this is the right approach  , any other suggestions ? without close the gdm service ? , we have ~ 1200 servers on sites so its huge task to stop the service on all sites

Comment: Whatever the solution, you’re going to have to apply it to all your servers anyway. Stopping and removing `gdm` is the right approach IMO.

Comment: if you have 1200 servers, **you have automation**, or a *gigantic* problem, anyways.. So, no, it's not a huge task at all. Any other solution wouldn't be easier than just uninstalling a package. I'm totally confused at what kind of operation you're running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a maximum file size limit for a process via `prlimit`

```
prlimit --fsize=1G:2G -p 12345
```

sets soft and hard file size limits for the process with PID `12345` to 1 and 2 gigabytes (or gibi ... not entirely sure), respectively. This may be done even after the process started.

Be aware that this will kill the process if the limit is reached. More in the `info` pages.

Comment: I don't know whether I would want to be this radical on `sss`'s `initgroups` files. In the end, this just tries to hide the underlying problem...